# Convert Hamiltonian to Ising Formulation or QUBO

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, d-wave, annealing, qubo

I have a tridiagonal Hamiltonian matrix that I need to convert to QUBO or Ising format to use D-Wave's quantum annealing solvers. For a generic tridiagonal:
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
c_1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
& c_2 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} \\
& & & c_{n-1} & a_n
\end{pmatrix}

How would I convert this to a either a QUBO or an Ising Formulation? I've seen how to do the reverse [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451075/how-can-i-explicitly-express-the-ising-hamiltonian-in-matrix-form), but it seems trying to invert this procedure is somewhat intractable.

Comment: Could you please add more details? Does the matrix represent quadratic part in your QUBO? What about linear part?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you decompose your matrix into a sum of Pauli operators such that there are no instances of $X$ and $Y$ (so basically a Pauli sum of $Z$, $I$ and any tensor product of these two), you can define a [`PauliSumOp`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.PauliSumOp.html) object and then use [`from_ising`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/optimization/stubs/qiskit_optimization.translators.from_ising.html#qiskit_optimization.translators.from_ising) to convert it into a QUBO program. The code to do this looks as follows:

```
from qiskit_optimization.translators import from_ising
from qiskit_optimization.converters import QuadraticProgramToQubo
from qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops import PauliSumOp

op   = PauliSumOp.from_list([("ZZ", 1), ("IZ", 2), ("Z", 3)]) # example operator
qp   = from_ising(op)
conv = QuadraticProgramToQubo()
qubo = conv.convert(qp)
```

The particular operator from my example outputs the following QUBO program:

```
\ This file has been generated by DOcplex
\ ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name: CPLEX

Minimize
 obj: [ - 24 x0^2 + 32 x0*x1 - 16 x1^2 ]/2 + 6
Subject To

Bounds
 0 <= x0 <= 1
 0 <= x1 <= 1

Binaries
 x0 x1
End
```

Comment: What happens if the decomposition contains an X or Y? The specific hamiltonian I am working with decomposes into a sum that contains II, IX, XX, and YY.